# Exclude commits from Phabricator revision

Tags: git, phabricator

I accidentally included the last five commits in a Phabricator revision, where as I should have only included the last one.

When I try `arc diff --update D100`, I see a `vim` page with a bunch of commented out info about my revision and nothing to edit:

```
# Updating D100: REVISION TITLE
#
# Enter a brief description of the changes included in this update.
# The first line is used as subject, next lines as comment.
#
# If you intended to create a new revision, use:
#  $ arc diff --create
```

Also the commits have been squashed together.
How can I exclude the four undesired ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, since the unwanted commits had been squashed together with only the last one I intended to include in the revision, I first needed to cherry-pick.

```
git cherry-pick COMMIT_HASH
```

Then I updated the revision using `arc diff --update D100 HEAD^`

Comment: I have 10 commits of which i want to keep the first 8, and remove the 9th and 10th commit, doing cherry-pick 8 commits seems tedious, how can i exclude the last 2 commits and update diff.

Comment: You can specify the base commit_id while creating or updating the diff, 
arc diff --update <diff_id> <base_commit_id>